# AWS lambda and Database

Tags: aws-lambda, connection-pooling

I have always learnt in theory that creating new connection to databases is costly operation. So we should keep open connection pool and use it for db operations.

When considering AWS lambda. Suppose lambda function wants to operate on db, then we need to create a connection to db. After operations, db needs to be closed. If simultaneously 100s of lambda function are executing then 100s of db connection open/close are being done. Which is theoretically bad pattern.

If this is so then is it inappropriate to use AWS lambda when db operations are involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need `DB` connection is closed, not reusing it in `Lambda` function?

Each `Lambda` function running means a `Container` and they will be alive for a while after running(several 10min and if you call it in succession, it will keep alive).

Being alive means that each `Lambda` function keeps the memory area after it is running so that it can reuse them.

For example, If you define a global variable in `Lambda` function like below.
(Though it is python code, I think you can understand because it is as simple as enough)

```
variable = 10

def lambda_function(event, context):
    global variable
    print(variable)  
    variable += 1
```

If the `Lambda` function is called at every 1 sec, it will print like the below.

```
10
11
12
13
14
.
.
.
```

As you can see, every `Lambda` function called is using the same global variable.
What if the global variable is DB connection? You can reuse them not re-opening connection at every lambda-call.

However, as you said if 100 `Lambda` functions are simultaneously executed, 100 connections will be opened since each `Lambda` concurrency means different `Containers` respectively, having different memory area.

But finally, 100 connections will be reused for sequential 100 simultaneous execution.

*---------- Edit ----------*

I agree with `@Arun`'s comment. My answer will be useful when traffic is steady and increasing and decreasing gradually so that the connections can be reused enough and closed by server-side's keep-alive. Radical increase and decrease of traffic could waste DB connection not closing appropriately.

*---------- Edit ----------* 2019-12-17

AWS announced the new feature `RDS proxy` though it is preview yet.
If you connect RDS through `RDS proxy`, it will manage DB connection pool(Lambda <-> RDS) for you.

For detail, reference this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/amazon-rds-proxy-available-in-preview/)

Comment: I am not fully convinced with your answer. Using global variable for DB connection in Lambda and not closing it will only be good if the lambda is very active throughout (i.e. If lambda keep receiving the hits), however in cases where lambda hits only for certain duration and does not hit again (say for another 5 ir 10 mins), then the container will start draining with the connection not closed properly. And if at the same time, users try to hit the lambda, it will try to create new containers and may not find appropriate number of connections availability.

Answer (score 1):

connection pooling working fine on Serverless
i.e.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: {Your Host},
    user: {Your Username},
    password: {Your Password},
    database: {Your Database},
    port: 3306
});
exports.main = function main (req) {
  let query = ""
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    return resolve({
      statusCode: 200,
      body: "Success"
    });
         })
}
```

Comment: I think question is miss understood. Creating connection pool definitely works. But the question is when lambda process is killed connection pool is not closed properly. One more issue is during autoscaling 100s of connection pool will be created which may exhaust max connection limit.