# Keep on getting MongoNetworkError connection 6 to xx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx closed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mongodb4.0

I keep on getting the below error in an AWS Lambda with Node.js 16 + MongoDB v4, this usually happens for a lambda that has high traffic, other lambdas seem fine with the current setup.

```
MongoNetworkError: connection 6 to xx.x.xx.xx:xxxxx closed at Connection.onClose (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:135:19)
```

MongoDB connection inside the lambda:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const logger = require(''); const log = logger(__filename);

const getDbClient = async (uri) => {
  try {
    log.info('Connecting to Mongo client...');
    const dbClient = await MongoClient.connect(uri);
    log.info('Connected to Mongo client');
    return dbClient;
  }
  catch (err) {
    log.error('Error encountered connecting to database: ', err);
    throw err;
  }
};

module.exports = {
  getDbClient
};
```

The mongodb uri has an option of `maxPoolSize=10` since I recently did an upgrade from MongoDB v3 to v4, and v4 has a `maxPoolSize of 100` by default and v3 had it to 10. https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/HEAD/etc/notes/CHANGES_4.0.0.md#connection-pool-options

MongoDB hardware:

3 x M4.XLarge(4Core/16GB RAM)

This issue started happening after I upgraded MongoDB driver from v3 to v4 and stopped checking inside the lambda if there is an existing connection so I can use it because in v4 apparently this is done automatically.

I used to use: `MongoClient.isConnected()` from MongoDB v3.

Do you guys have any idea what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll just post an answer :D

I think your Lambda function is on extremely high traffic now, so it's even over the pool size of mongodb

Comment: By increasing the `maxPoolSize` value to 20 or even more causes more errors. Not really sure if this is the issue.

Comment: obviously your errors come from the Mongo connection. I think the main problem is that your function is on very high traffic and making too many connections to Mongo

Comment: What if you increase maxPoolSize to 20 but your function is creating 40 connections to mongo? I think you will still get the same errors

Comment: I am using this at a big level, think about thousands of connections at a time.

Comment: @NicolaeMaties you have thousand of connections while the maximum connections that mongo supports just 100... Lambda function has some mechanisms to reuse the database connection, have you tried that?

Comment: I am doing that already, reusing the connections otherwise I would have more errors and more frequently than now.

Comment: Ok so your function is reusing the connections. Maybe your functions are simultaneously executed. "if 100 Lambda functions are simultaneously executed, 100 connections will be opened since each Lambda concurrency means different Containers respectively, having different memory area." as I found from this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974548/aws-lambda-and-database. I hope it will help

Comment: Btw, forgot to mention: "This issue started happening after I upgraded MongoDB driver from v3 to v4 and stopped checking inside the lambda if there is an existing connection so I can use it because in v4 apparently this is done automatically."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).